# In a line specific word convert to table format

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

***The Physical Study of DEEPAK  Barin: 34 is ST#: 3, VISUAL: 593, Chest: 56, EYES(0: LV, 1: HV): 0***

Like this, so many lines are here. I want the output in a table format like this.

```
Barin |  ST  | VISUAL | Chest | LV | HV 
 34   |   3  |   593  | 56    | 1  | 0
```

Comment: In what kind of file are you storing your data?

Comment: Text file or  Anything could be fine, but here am not storing data I am fetching from a log. I want logic.

Comment: Shouldn't the LV -> 0 instead of 1? ( Also HV -> instead of 0.... )

Comment: yes man it should be lv ->1 and hv -> 0

Comment: From the comment on my answer below I assume now that you are asking about parsing the input line? Can you clarify if the input value to get is a line of text which is *always* in the form `The Physical Study of DEEPAK Barin: 34 is ST#: 3, VISUAL: 593, Chest: 56, EYES(0: LV, 1: HV): 0`?

Comment: Yes, line always in this form.

Comment: I have updated my response with a simple regex-based parser

Answer (score 0):

First, the lines must be parsed. Looking at the line format we can conclude the following:

- It is not trivial to parse using simple string manipulation (indices, splits, partitioning, ...)
- Using a full-fledged parser like [pyparsing](https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing) or [ply](https://pypi.org/project/ply/) might is overkill if the lines don't vary in structure too much.
- [Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) are a good fit for this

Here is an example function which parses the line into named-tuples using the [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module:

```
import re
from collections import namedtuple

import rapidtables

Row = namedtuple('Row', 'title age st visual chest lv hv')
PATTERN = re.compile(
    r'^(.*?): '
    r'(\d+) is '
    r'ST#: (\d+), '
    r'VISUAL: (\d+), '
    r'Chest: (\d+), '
    r'EYES\((\d+): LV, '
    r'(\d+): HV\): '
    r'(\d+)')


def parse_line(line):
    # type: (str) -> Optional[Row]
    """
    Parses a line into a named-tuple

    Example:

    >>> parse_line('The Physical Study of DEEPAK Barin: 34 is ST#: 3, VISUAL: 593, Chest: 56, EYES(0: LV, 1: HV): 0')
    Row(title='The Physical Study of DEEPAK Barin', age=34, st=3, visual=593, chest=56, lv=0, hv=1)
    """
    match = PATTERN.match(line)
    if not match:
        # Line did not match the expected pattern
        return None

    # As we have a match, we can now unpack the groups from the regex
    title, age, st, visual, chest, lv, hv, unknown = match.groups()

    # The regex returns strings, we convert them to more manageable data-types
    # here, because this should be part of the parsing, and should not be
    # forced upon downstream code.
    output = Row(
        title,
        int(age),
        int(st),
        int(visual),
        int(chest),
        int(lv),
        int(hv)
    )
    return output
```

Using this parsing function, you can use [rapidtables](https://github.com/alttch/rapidtables) to easily format data like this:

```
import rapidtables

with open('textfile') as infile:
    parsed_lines = [parse_line(line.strip()) for line in infile]
table = rapidtables.make_table(parsed_lines , tablefmt='simple')
print(table)
```

Comment: It's in a paragraph . Not like dict or list.

Comment: do you have any other logic for this scenario? without using rapidtables modules/package .

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question. I assumed that you have nailed down the parsing and wanted a way to nicely format it as a table. If you are asking about the parsing specifically you may need to reword your question. And if you can show some code you tried, it might help understand the problem better.